# Unmark checkbox when there is no more TR and TABLE goes hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm working on this function for remove any marked checkbox in a `selector` container element. The code works fine but has a small problem: I'm not able to uncheck the first checkbox (the one that toggle all the checkboxes in a `selector2` container). Now this is the code for remove the checked checkboxes:

```
function eliminarMarcados(selector, toggleMsg, msgSelector) {
    $(selector + " input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").not('.tableHead').remove();

    if (toggleMsg) {
        if ($(selector + " tbody tr").length == 0) {
            $(msgSelector).show();
            $(selector).hide();

            // 1st test didn't work since it's not right
            //$(selector + " tr").hasClass('tableHead').$(selector + " input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
$("#btnEliminarNorma").on('click', function () {
    eliminarMarcados("#tablaNorma", true, "#alertSinNorma");
});
```

This is the code I'm using for toggle all checkboxes checked:

```
function marcarTodosCheck(selChk, tableBody) {
    $(selChk).on('click', function () {
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle).trigger("change");
    });

    $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(selChk).prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
        } else if ($(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").length == $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
            $(selChk).prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
        }
    });
}
```

And I call it as follow:

```
marcarTodosCheck("#toggleCheckNorma", "#tablaNorma");
```

And this is the HTML code behind this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="tablaNorma">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableHead">
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="toggleCheckNorma" name="toggleCheckNorma"></th>
            <th>Nro.</th>
            <th>Norma COVENIN</th>
            <th>Año de Publicación</th>
            <th>Comité Técnico</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="normaBody">
        <tr class="">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="5"></td>
            <td>382</td><td>Sit alias sit.</td>
            <td>1970</td><td>Velit eum.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
            <td>38362</td>
            <td>Et voluptatem.</td><td>1976</td>
            <td>Et voluptatem.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How I can unmark the first checkbox?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv5n2ou7/) with an additional `<button id="btnEliminarNorma">Uncheck</button>` to remove the checkmarks and the adjustment of your first approach in the `function eliminarMarcados()` :

```
$(selector).find(" input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
```